# What is wrong with this many-to-many relationship in EF code-first

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on Code First , EF 6.0 and trying to implement Many to Many relationship between Request and Tag tables.

The relationships are set correctly as:

```
HasMany(b => b.Tags).WithMany().Map(mc => mc.MapLeftKey("RequestID").MapRightKey("TagID").ToTable("requesttags"));
```

Everything looks alright. However, when it comes to insert tags against Request, I inserting in three ways:

```
>   if (request.Tags == null)
>             {
>                 entity.Tags = new List<Tag>();
>             }
>              // 1 way get the tag and then insert.
>             var tag = _tagService.Get(1);
               // 2 and 3 way hard code id with the name. 
>             var tags = new List<Tag> {tag, new Tag {Name = ".Net", ID = 2}, new Tag {Name = "C#"}};
> 
>             request.Tags.AddRange(tags);
```

The insert operation is performed. However, when I see the end result: the first tag has made a reference correctly. However for two tags, even though ID and Names are matching, still it is creating a new record in Tag table and making a reference.

My thought are because the first tag object is get from the database and it is attached. But why do I have to attach?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why do I have to attach?

Because they are disconnected objects and will be treated as new objects. The moment you add the `tags` into `request.Tags`, both of them will be marked as Added because EF doesn't know that both of them are existing entities.

You can check the state of each tag by simply loop the `Tags`.

```
request.Tags.AddRange(tags);
foreach(var tag in tags)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dbContext.Entry(tag).State);
}
```

The output should be like:

```
Unchanged
Added
Added
```

> How can I solve this?

Just `Attach` it or mark it as `Unchanged` for the disconnected objects.

```
dbContext.Entry(tags[1]).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
// equals to dbContext.Set<Tag>().Attach(tags[1]);
dbContext.Entry(tags[2]).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
// equals to dbContext.Set<Tag>().Attach(tags[2]);
```

And make sure both entities are really existing entities, if not `DbUpdateException` will be thrown when calling `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I understand and I will follow the same. however, I was in the impression that there is some application wide way to manage it. In other words, all of my entities have got one field called ID and if I can tell somehow an EF that hey this is the field through which you will check and find before you insert/ update. That way I don't have to loop through and change the state.

Comment: @codebased, There is no way EF knows what state of each disconnected object, EF will just treat them as new object, even if the ID is not 0 or not Guid Empty, they will still be added in this case. _Entity Framework takes care of tracking the state of entities while they are connected to a context, but in disconnected or N-Tier scenarios you can let EF know what state your entities should be in._ - [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx). If you are looking for an elegant solution, you can use [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff)